# Error when invoking the getPort of a wsdl with SpringBoot 2.7.12 AND javax

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, jax-rs, jax-ws

I have a problem with the implementation of the rest service and a local library made from a wsdl and the wsimport command based on Springboot and Apache CXF. When trying to use the library the following error is generated.

```
ERROR Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException\] with root cause
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

```java
@WebServiceClient(name = "WSCommonEmailEndPoint", targetNamespace = "http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", wsdlLocation = "https://wsPruebas201.local.example.corp:8080/WarWSCommonEmail/WSCommonEmailEndPoint/WSCommonEmailEndPoint.wsdl")
public class WSCommonEmailEndPoint extends Service {
    private final static URL WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME = new QName("http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", "WSCommonEmailEndPoint");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://wsPruebas201.local.example.corp:8080/WarWSCommonEmail/WSCommonEmailEndPoint/WSCommonEmailEndPoint.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME);
    }
    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME, features);
    }
    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME);
    }
    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_QNAME, features);
    }
    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }
    public WSCommonEmailEndPoint(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }
    @WebEndpoint(name = "CommonEmailServicePort")
    public CommonEmailService getCommonEmailServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", "CommonEmailServicePort"), CommonEmailService.class);
    }
    @WebEndpoint(name = "CommonEmailServicePort")
    public CommonEmailService getCommonEmailServicePort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://servicio.ws.commonEmail.ban.example/", "CommonEmailServicePort"), CommonEmailService.class, features);
    }
    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return WSCOMMONEMAILENDPOINT_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

The invocation to the wsdl webservice was expected to be executed, I see no error in the WSCommonEmailEndPoint class, I have another project that consumes a wsdl in a similar way.

Comment: at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
 at example.ban.commonemail.ws.wsdl.WSCommonEmailEndPoint.getCommonEmailServicePort(WSCommonEmailEndPoint.java:98)